# Convert 3-momentum vectors to spherical coordinate system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, coordinate-systems, vectors

I have the 3 momentum vectors $(P_x, P_y, P_z)$ describing the position of a particle and I have to convert these coordinates to the corresponding spherical ones $(\varphi, \theta, r)$.

The equations I came up with are:

- $\theta=\tan^{-1} \frac{P_x}{P_y}$
- $\varphi=\tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{P_x^2 + P_y^2}}{P_z}$
- $r=\sqrt{P_x^2 + P_y^2 + P_z^2}$

Are these correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformations for turning the momentum components in Cartesian coordinates $(p_x,p_y,p_z)$ to the Cartesian ones $(p_r=p,p_{\phi},p_{\theta})$ is given by
$$p_x=p\sin\theta\sin\phi,\ p_y=p\sin\theta\sin\phi,\ p_z=p\cos\theta$$
where $p=\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2}$.

Reversing the latter shall give you the transformations that take you from the Cartesian to the spherical coordinates. Furthermore, the choice I have made is not singular.

So, to apply all these to your case, a choice you can make is
$\theta=\cos^{-1}\Big(\frac{p_z}{p}\Big)=\tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2}}{p_z}\Big),\ 
\phi=tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{p_y}{p_x}\Big)$

In short, yes, you are correct if you have defined your $\theta$ to be my $\phi$ and your $\phi$ to be my $\theta$